# How can I use thymleaf with spring security, using Keycloak inside the .html files?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, keycloak

I'm using `keycloak` for authentication and authorization with `Spring Boot` and `Thymeleaf`.

I'm trying to secure some areas, for example if the user has the role `ROLE_TEC`, I have to hide some part of the view, so I'm doing the following:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_TEC')">
//some html
</li>
```

The user that I'm using has that role, but I can't see that piece of page.
Why?

Do I have to add any configuration about thymeleaf for keycloak or Spring security?

**EDIT**

If I use: 
`<span sec:authentication="authorities"></span>`

I obtain this:

```
[KeycloakRole{role='TEC'}, KeycloakRole{role='USER'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the solution:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('TEC')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_TEC'')')}"
//some html
</li>
```